# AngularJS app won't load in iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, mechanicalturk

I'm running in to an issue displaying an angularjs app in an iframe. A little bit of context: I'm developing a page to be displayed as an external question for Amazon's Mechanical Turk. The hit page loads but the question iframe is blank and is not loading the question on example.com/hit/1234

> Refused to display * in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=23G9U8P9Y38TKA4NLVLYLM0JTYGGXM

I've researched the error and its generally an issue with the page being embedded in the iframe setting headers to refuse this. I wrote the page and am not setting those headers. Help?

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to angular.  `X-frame-options` is a response header being sent by your web server.  You should be able to modify it but it will require server configuration.

More info about the header here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Thanks. I wrote the server backend so no problem updating headers.

Comment: This won't work in Chrome or Firefox? Am I reading that correctly? This is confusing as Amazon's external question requires you to self host and if those browers don't support this header then would those workers not see hits with external questions?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not familiar with the details of this header.  Maybe it's time for a new question...